# Exclusive lock vs atomic(?) increment/decrement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking

We're working on implementing an account with virtual currency in our app and we need to update account balance (classic, yeah?).

Let's say we have an `accounts` table with `user_id` and `balance` fields.
`user_id` is unique identifier for the sake of demonstration here.

First, classic solution with placing an exclusive lock to user's account row:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- select user's account and lock it
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id = :userId FOR UPDATE;

-- Check balance in app.
-- If balance is not enough to do the transaction
-- -- Rollback. Show user an error with remaining balance.
-- else
-- -- update account balance in db
UPDATE accounts SET balance= :newBalance WHERE user_id = :userId;
-- insert transaction
INSERT INTO transactions (...) VALUES (...);
COMMIT;
```

Now what if we try something different, like this:

```
-- calculate amount to be withdrawn from user's account in app

START TRANSACTION;

-- Update balance only if new balance will be positive
-- Can be done with IF, CASE or an extra WHERE clause
UPDATE account
SET balance = IF(balance >= :transactionAmount, balance - :transactionAmount, balance)
WHERE user_id = :userId;

-- Process result of above query in app.
-- If 0 rows were updated (balance was not enough)
-- -- Rollback transaction, read new balance and show an error to user with updated balance.
-- else
-- --insert transaction and commit
INSERT INTO transactions (...) VALUES (...);
COMMIT;
```

I tried the 2nd solution with 2 connections running queries manually, seems to work as expected. Transaction isolation level was the default one - repeatable reads.
Is it reliable? Any pitfalls? What about performance? Why the 1st solution is more widely suggested?

UPD: modified 1st example to be more clear about the logic executed in app between SELECT and UPDATE queries.

Comment: It's not an app serious enough to store failed transaction attempt. We only need to store successful transactions.